# Linear independence of the basis of $F/IF$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

I'm working through the exercises of Rotman's Homological Algebra book. Exercise 2.12 wants to prove that if $I$ is a maximal ideal in a commutative ring $R$ and $X$ is a basis of a free $R$-module $F$ then $F/IF$ is a vector space over $R/I$ and has basis $\{ x + IF \mid x \in X \}$.

I had no troubles except proving that the basis is linearly independent. For that we take $x_1, \dots, x_n \in X$ and $r_1, \dots, r_n \in R$ with
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(r_i + I)(x_i + IF)} = (\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{r_ix_i}) + IF = 0
$$
and $x_i - x_j \notin IF$ for $i \neq j$. Thus, $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{r_ix_i} \in IF$. Now, I argue that every element in $IF$ can be written as $\sum_{j=1}^{m}{s_jx_j}$ for $s_j \in I$ and $x_j \in X$: Any element of $IF$ can be written as $\sum_{j=1}^{m}{s_jy_j}$ for $s_j \in I$ and $y_j \in F$. Now, as $X$ is a basis of $F$, every $y_j$ can be written as linear combination of elements of $X$. Inserting these combinations and using the properties of an ideal yields the desired formula.

Back to the proof, I can write $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{r_ix_i} = \sum_{j=1}^{m}{s_jx_j'}$ with $s_j \in I$ and $x_j' \in X$. Now, reordering terms, and setting $r_i$ or $s_i$ to $0$ if not defined wlog we can write $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{r_ix_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{s_ix_i}$. But $X$ is a basis, so we have that $r_i = s_i \in I$.

My problem is now that I never used that the $x_i$ come from different cosets. So, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ come from the same coset I would have that $1x_1 - 1x_2 \in IF$, but $1 \notin I$, but I do not see where my argument above exactly breaks.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Note that it is not possible that $x_1-x_2\in IF$, as otherwise, by your discussion how every element from $IF$ is written, you get that $1\in I$.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I got confused by the way Rotman formulated the exercise, which implied for me that it would be possible that x's get identified. But then I showed even more than necessary. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SMM May you upgrade your comment to an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, no problem, I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible that $x_1-x_2\in IF$. By your discussion how every element from $IF$ is written, you get that $1\in I$. So, you are not using that $x_i$'s come from different cosets; this is a consequence of linear independence which you proved.

Answer (score 1):

An element of $IF$ can be written as
$$
y=\sum_{k=1}^n a_ky_k
$$
with $a_k\in I$ and $y_k\in F$. By definition of basis,
$$
y_k=\sum_{x\in X}r_{x,k}x
$$
(only a finite number of $r_{x,k}$ are nonzero) so we have
$$
y=\sum_{x\in X}\Bigl(\,\sum_{k=1}^n a_kr_{x,k}\Bigr)x
$$
Hence we can write
$$
y=\sum_{x\in X}s_{x}x \tag{*}
$$
with $s_x\in I$. The converse is clearly also true. Note that the coefficients are unique.

Now, if
$$
\sum_{x\in X}(r_x+I)(x+IF)=0
$$
we get
$$
\sum_{x\in X}r_xx\in IF
$$
and therefore $r_x\in I$, for every $x\in X$.

This proves linear independence (I'm afraid your proof is wrong from the beginning).

The problem you seem to have about $x_i-x_j\notin IF$ is a non issue, really. Anyway, there are no distinct elements $x,y\in X$ such that $x+IF=y+IF$, because this would imply $x-y\in IF$, so, by the characterization (*), $1\in I$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem I had was that in the definition of linear independence the $x_i$'s have to be distinct, which is normally a trivial assumption, but working with equivalence classes that is a non-trivial assumption, as different x's might be in the same equivalence class, but as pointed out in the other answer the proof also shows this is not possible.

Comment: @Ikarus There's no reason for requiring the vector to be distinct in order to state linear independence. If two of the vectors are the same, you'll easily see that the list of vectors is not linearly independent. Anyway, in this case it is trivial, because $1\notin I$.

Comment: But if I want to prove linear independence, I should only consider linear combinations where all vectors differ and then show that all coefficients are $0$, otherwise i would also consider representations like $x - x = 0$. So, when using cosets that means that i get exactly the assumption that $x_i - x_j \notin IF$ for all $i \neq j$ and I wondered why I did not have to use that assumption.

Comment: @Ikarus The linear combination $1x-1x=0$ surely has nonzero coefficients, doesn't it?  Just think to lists of vectors, that is, functions from some set $I$ to the vector space. If the function is not injective, then the list of vectors is not linearly independent.There is no advantage (and some disadvantages) in considering *sets* of vectors.

Comment: Exactly, I think we are talking at cross-purposes, as you consider linear independence of a list of vectors and I of a set of vectors. Let me phrase the problem I had again with a list: First, we do not know if two different $x$ might get identified, so we list all cosets, and take representants $x_i$ of these cosets. Then the representants fulfil $x_i - x_j \notin IF$, but I was confused as the argument never used that relation. As pointed out in the other answer in fact the argument shows that no two different $x$ get identified. I think in your proof you are implicitly using this result.

Comment: @Ikarus No, I'm not implicitly using the result. If there existed distinct $x_i,x_j$ such that $x_i+IF=x_j+IF$ you cannot prove that the coefficients are all zero, because it would be false. Anyway, I added the part you insist on.

Comment: Obviously I do not want to annoy you, sorry if I am, but arent you using this fact when you consider the sum over all $x \in X$ instead over all representants of the cosets in the last two sums? Anyhow, thank you for taking your time.

Comment: @Ikarus No, really. I consider an arbitrary sum (of just a finite number of terms, even if the index set is infinite, but this is not of a concern) and assume it is zero. If two of the $x+IF$ terms were equal, then it would be clearly false that the coefficients are necessarily zero. Since I'm able to prove that indeed all the coefficients are zero, I get *as a consequence* that $x_1+IF$ cannot equal $x_2+IF$ if $x_1,x_2$ are distinct members of $X$.

Comment: Ah I see, I was a bit confused how you precisely meant to argue. Thanks!